# Problem in SMOTE oversampling in a classification problem

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, classification, smote

My dataset contains 130 features, all in z-score format, and 100 labels.
I am trying to train a classifier on this dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
train_data = pd.read_csv('data_train.csv')
test_data = pd.read_csv('data_test.csv')

X_test = test_data.drop(['labels'], axis=1)
y_test = test_data['labels'].astype('string')
X_train = train_data.drop(['labels'], axis=1)
y_train = train_data['labels'].astype('string')
```

This is the distribution of the labels:

[image]

I used three classifiers (Naive Bayes, Random Forest, Neural network with Keras). I obtain about 60% accuracy with the three classifiers.

For example with this code I obtain 57% accuracy.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
y_pred = gnb.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
(y_test == y_pred).sum()/X_test.shape[0]
```

I used SMOTE to reduce the imbalance in the labels distribution.

```
oversample = SMOTE()
X_train, y_train = oversample.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
y_train.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

This is the distribution of labels in the balanced dataset:

[image]

After running the oversampling code, I rerun the same classifier on the oversampled data. The accuracy drop to 0:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
y_pred = gnb.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
(y_test == y_pred).sum()/X_test.shape[0]
```

Accuracy here is 0, and the same thing happen to all other classifiers.

Do you have any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

in case of **Smote technique** what happens is that to balance the dataset we create **synthetic data points** based on the original data points so basically it does not copy those data points but rather creates the data points slight varied from the original one.

So now, in case of directly using the imbalanced dataset the classifier will work well with the majority one and give you the accuracy however when **SMOTE** is used then now the dataset is balanced so it will predict the minority classes better but the overall accuracy will decrease

Also **accuracy** is not the right parameter for the imbalanced dataset try with others like F1 Score and AUC. Also use the classification report and see whether the other parameters like recall and precision improved or not Smote does help in their improvement but not accuracy

You can try SMOTE-ENN where under-sampling of the class with higher values and over-sampling of minority will take place so you will reach at an intermediate value.

Comment: I am afraid this does not provide an answer to the question; OP asks for an explanation of the performance of the specific algorithm used, not for recommendations of alternative algorithms.

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut I did not mention the explanation I will edit my answer

Comment: Good job - now it is indeed an answer.